# How do I symbolically link /etc/resolv.conf to /var/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf in Yocto

Tags: systemd, networkmanager, yocto, systemd-resolved

I'm trying to setup a Yocto build using NetworkManager v1.22.16 and systemd 244.5. [systemd-resolved - /etc/resolv.conf](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html#/etc/resolv.conf)  recommends I setup /etc/resolv.conf as a symbolic link to /var/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf. Initially it was linked to /etc/resolv-conf.NetworkManager but I've fixed that by adding a networkmanager_%.bbappend file with:

```
ALTERNATIVE_${PN} = ""
```

But now I find /etc/resolv.conf is a symbolic link to /etc/resolv-conf.systemd, which is itself a symbolic link to /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf. I'm not sure where this is coming from, possibly after the device boots. Everything seems to work so is this ok? Or do I still need to override the build to make /etc/resolv.conf a symbolic link to /var/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf?